# error when using loop to input data to sqlite3 database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have already created a database using the DB browser and I want to put all the research result I get from PubMed into the database including the title and article, I am able to get them out but when I input them to the database I keep getting error.

here is my code

```
import requests
import re
num=[]
page=1
for i in range(1,page+1):
    try:
        html=requests.get(f"https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=covid19&page={i}").text
        num.extend((re.findall('class="docsum-title"\s+href="(.*?)"',html)))
    except:
        continue
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in num]) 
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', listToStr)

from pubmed_lookup import PubMedLookup
from pubmed_lookup import Publication
import sqlite3
for i in numbers:
    email = 'litsunchak@gmail.com'
    url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/'+i
    lookup = PubMedLookup(url, email)
    publication = Publication(lookup)
    
    #define connection
    db = sqlite3.connect('pubMed.db')
    #create cursor to execute your equest
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS(pubmed_data)')
    c.execute('insert into pubmed_data(title,article) values(?,? )', (publication.title, repr(publication.abstract)))
    
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    
    print('Insert ok')
```

this is the error I get,

```
OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

really need some help

Answer (score 0):

Your `CREATE TABLE` statement is wrong.
The correct way to do it is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pubmed_data (title TEXT, article TEXT)
```

The name of the table must be written before the parentheses and inside the parentheses you list all the columns of the new table.
See this: [CREATE TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)